# Mongo Compaas filter within Projection

Tags: mongodb

Recently I am facing a challenege while creating a query in Mongo Compass. Below is the scenario.
I have a set of documents in mongo db like below:

```
{
  _id :1,
  'people':[
   {
     'grade' : ['A','B'],
     'stream': [ {
          'stream_id: 'CSE',
          'stream_name': 'COMPUTER'
           },
          {
          'stream_id: 'ECE',
          'stream_name': 'ELECTRONICS'
          },
          ]
   },
   {
    'grade' : ['B'],
    'stream': [ {
            'stream_id: 'IT',
            'stream_name': 'INFORMATION_TECH'
             }
             ]
    }

  ]
}
```

I need to find the 'PEOPLE' element which has grade as 'A' and stream_name as 'CSE'. So basically I want this output:

```
{
_id :1,
'people':[
{
'grade' : ['A','B'],
'stream': [ {
'stream_id: 'CSE',
'stream_name': 'COMPUTER'
}
]
]}
```

I have tried all the $elemMatch features but it's returning the whole document not only that particular index of the array. Please if anyone is aware of mongo compass, let me know.

Mongo is fun it seems :)

Comment: Please have a look if the answer helpful https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregations

- `$unwind` to deconstruct the array
- `$match` to get necessary documents, others will be eliminated
- `$filter` to filter the stream, since we get all the documents that passes the condition, we need to filter the stream objects which equal to condition
- `$group` to reconstruct the array that we already deconstructed in first step

here is the code

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $unwind: "$people" },
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $and: [
          { $in: [  "A", "$people.grade" ] },
          { $in: [ "CSE", "$people.stream.stream_id" ] }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      "people.stream": {
        $filter: {
          input: "$people.stream",
          cond: { $eq: [ "$$this.stream_id", "CSE" ] }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      people: { $push: "$people" }
    }
  }
])
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/5sEvEqxm1ZX)**